# Editable fields in jsPDF documents do not print

Tags: jspdf

I have created a pdf document with editable fields, using jsPDF. Everything looks great, but when I print it, the field values are not included.
This is some sample code (from jsPDF/examples/js/AcroForm.js) to test it:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(10, 65, 'TextField:');
var textField = new TextField();
textField.Rect = [50, 50, 120, 80];
textField.multiline = true;
textField.V = "The quick brown fox ate the lazy mouse The quick brown fox ate the lazy mouse The quick brown fox ate the lazy mouse";
textField.T = "TestTextBox";
doc.addField(textField);
doc.save('Test.pdf');
```

Do I need to do something else to be able to print the field text? I have opened the resulting pdf-file in Acrobat, and it recognizes the fields, but will not print the content.

Comment: Sorry I can't help, but can I ask where you found documentation of the `textField` options? I was looking for that for days before I stumbled across this question.

Comment: Just Google 'jspdf acroform', e.g. https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/examples/js/AcroForm.js . I haven't really looked for or found more detail than this.

Comment: @Trebard, your code works for me in 2019 using:   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

You can use AcroFormTextField.

```
  var doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.text(10, 65, 'TextField:');
  var textField = new AcroFormTextField();
  textField.Rect = [300, 150, 120, 80];
  textField.multiline = true;
  textField.V = "The quick brown fox ate the lazy mouse The quick brown fox ate the lazy mouse The quick brown fox ate the lazy mouse";
  textField.T = "TestTextBox";
  doc.addField(textField);
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP question was Version 1
Also the core issue is that AcroField appearances for display and print can be set independently, thus the field shows but may not print in Acrobat or similar viewers.
[image]

Syntax has changed for Version 2 but there is a setting for **`textField.showWhenPrinted`** this can be `= true` or  `= false` but default should be true

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- use latest cdnjs 2.5.1 version or the min(imised) variant -->.
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.js" integrity="sha512-Bw9Zj8x4giJb3OmlMiMaGbNrFr0ERD2f9jL3en5FmcTXLhkI+fKyXVeyGyxKMIl1RfgcCBDprJJt4JvlglEb3A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
// for version 2 standalone include
window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;

/* global jsPDF */

var doc = new jsPDF();

// note the new name changes
var {TextField} = jsPDF.AcroForm;

doc.text(10, 10, 'Hello Field$');
doc.text('A TextField:', 10, 85);

var textField = new TextField();

//Here is the critical one since field appearence can be on/off for screen and or print
textField.showWhenPrinted = true;

textField.Rect = [50, 50, 120, 80];
textField.fontSize = 25;
textField.multiline = true;
textField.value = "The quick brown fox ate the lazy mouse The quick brown fox ate the lazy mouse The quick brown fox ate the lazy mouse"; //
textField.fieldName = "TestTextBox";

doc.addField(textField);

doc.save('Test.pdf');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]